# Can not use the `gettext` which is installed by brew

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, homebrew

After I install the `gettext` in my mac:

I use the `brew install gettext` command installed it.

```
...    
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.8.1: 1,934 files, 16.9MB
```

I can not use the `gettext` still.

```
$ gettext --help
-bash: gettext: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That formula doesn't link - you can do it by hand if you require it:

> This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local, because macOS provides the BSD gettext library & some software gets confused if both are in the library path.

The maintainers recommend:

> If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
>     echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

You can even get a more explicit warning by trying to link it manually:

> $brew link gettext.
>
> Warning: gettext is keg-only and must be linked with --force.
>
> Note that doing so can interfere with building software.

If you're sure you need it linked everywhere:

```
brew link gettext --force
```

See this SU thread for details https://superuser.com/questions/747324/brew-install-gettext-should-i-force-link-it

Comment: Also you can add it to `oh-my-zsh` -> echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

Answer (score 0):

I tried running this `brew link gettext --force`, but I was getting:

```
$ brew install gettext
Warning: gettext 0.20.2 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 0.20.2, run `brew reinstall gettext`

$ brew link gettext --force
Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: gettext
If you need to have gettext first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find gettext you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include"
```

Then, I just added it to the system path with:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Related:

1. [Can not use the `gettext` which is installed by brew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299048/can-not-use-the-gettext-which-is-installed-by-brew)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670295/homebrew-refusing-to-link-openssl
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940383/how-to-install-gettext-on-macos-x
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422345/installed-just-not-linked
5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644349/msgmerge-on-macos-catalina